# fullcalendar two-shift calendar, coloring weeks

Tags: javascript, css, fullcalendar

is it posible in fullcalendar make double color calendar that odd weeks are in color x and even in y color?

https://fullcalendar.io/#demos

like this:

[image]

Comment: The only way I can see to do it would be to work out yourself which days will be in each row for a given month, and then find all the `<td>`s whose `data-date` attribute contains a day in the rows you want to colour, and set their background colour.

Comment: Either that or you copy the code for the "month" view from the fullCalendar source code and create a [custom view](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js) which implements the requirement automatically. I think those are your options - I can't see anything else in the settings or in the HTML which would allow you to do this.

Comment: Try styling `.fc-row:nth-child(odd) .fc-bg {background-color: white;} .fc-row:nth-child(even) fc-bg {background-color: wheat;}`

Answer (score 2):

As I see FC has something like this in it's `html` structure:

```
<div class="fc-day-grid">
  <div class="fc-row fc-week">
    <div class="fc-bg">
      <!-- other fc elements-->
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- other similar blocks of weeks-rows like above -->
</div>
```

You could customize `fc-bg` class of every even child of `fc-day-grid` like

```
.fc-row:nth-child(even) .fc-bg {
  background-color: #fcf8e3;
}
```

Look example in snippet.

```css
.fc-day-grid .fc-bg {
  height: 50px;
  border: solid 1px black
}

.fc-row:nth-child(even) .fc-bg {
  background-color: #fcf8e3;
}
```

```html
<div class="fc-day-grid">
  <div class="fc-row fc-week">
    <div class="fc-bg">
      <!-- other fc elements-->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fc-row fc-week">
    <div class="fc-bg">
      <!-- other fc elements-->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fc-row fc-week">
    <div class="fc-bg">
      <!-- other fc elements-->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fc-row fc-week">
    <div class="fc-bg">
      <!-- other fc elements-->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fc-row fc-week">
    <div class="fc-bg">
      <!-- other fc elements-->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fc-row fc-week">
    <div class="fc-bg">
      <!-- other fc elements-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```